# Unable to use PowerMockito with PowerMockRunnerDelegate set as SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4, powermockito

I am trying to integrate PowerMockito with my spring boot unit test cases suite.
I am using consul to fetch my app configuration from the cloud.I am getting following exception while running junit testcases :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulConfigBootstrapConfiguration$ConsulPropertySourceConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'consul': Error creating bean with name 'consulClient' defined in org.springframework.cloud.consul.ConsulAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient]: Factory method 'consulClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consulClient' defined in org.springframework.cloud.consul.ConsulAutoConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient]: Factory method 'consulClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient
```

Following is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableScheduling
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "scheduler")
class TestApplication{
}


@ActiveProfiles("abc")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(KafkaClientUtil.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=TestApplication.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ProcessorTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestClient Client;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws JsonProcessingException {


    }

}
```

Comment: do you have any static initialisation in `ConsulRawClient`?

Comment: @ArthurZagretdinov ConsulRawClient is part of library. We don't have control over its source code